# How can i pass the value of a static variable to a method?

Tags: java

I wrote down a simple program to demonstrate the use of the static keyword. I've also typed a method to calculate the square of the variable and have initialized the value of the static variable in the main class.

```
class staticdemo{
public static int stvar;

void square(int stvar){
    System.out.println("" + stvar*stvar);
}

}
public class statictest {
public static void main(String args[]){
    staticdemo.stvar = 10;  
int s = staticdemo.stvar;
    square(s); //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR!
}
}
```

the exact error i get is " the method square(int) is undefined for the type statictest"

how can i execute the method with a static variable?

Comment: __JavaScript__ ???

Comment: Label the question with the correct code tag and you will get some answers. This is not Javascript.

Comment: Should be `staticdemo.square` instead of `square`. I vote to close this as low-quality question.

Comment: @Everv0id: Only if `square` is `static`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right. Haste makes waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that you're passing a static field (not variable) into the method. It's that you're trying to call an *instance* method without an instance.

Either:

1. Make `square` `static` as well, so you can call it from `main`, or
2. Create an instance in `main` to call it on:

   ```
   new staticdemo().square(staticdemo.stvar);
   ```

I'd also strongly urge you not to use the same name for a static field (`stvar`) and a function parameter (`stvar` in `square`). It's just asking for confusion and trouble.

Also suggest following standard Java naming conventions, even in your own test code, but particularly when asking others for help.

So perhaps:

```
class StaticDemo {
    public static int stvar;

    public static void square(int s) {
    //     ^^^^^^                 ^
        System.out.println("" + s * s);
    //                          ^   ^
    }
}

public class StaticTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StaticDemo.square(StaticDemo.stvar);
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Or alternately:

```
class StaticDemo {
    public static int stvar;

    public void square(int s) {
    //                     ^
        System.out.println("" + s * s);
    //                          ^   ^
    }
}

public class StaticTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new StaticDemo().square(StaticDemo.stvar);
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your method should also be static

Answer (score 0):

This method must be static

`void square(int stvar)` if you want to call it from an static context

another more elegant and ***OOP*** way would be to declare an object of the class, encapsulate its members by declaring them private

i.e.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    staticdemo.stvar = 10;  
    int s = staticdemo.stvar;
    staticdemo foo = new staticdemo();

    foo.square(s); //HERE will work fine!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the nonstatic method directly. You have to create an object for the staticdemo class then you can call the method using the oobject.
Inside the main method enter 
staticdemo st=new staticdemo();
st.square(s);